# Record and store a path of a curved shape

Tags: java, android, record, shapes

I would like to record the user's input in my drawing application. It can draw whatever he wants, not only shape with straight line. How can I record, in a single path, all the moves that the user does when he draws, for example, a particular circle? This is my method, where there is the **System.out.println()** is where I would push the method to save the Path.

````
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                System.out.println(touchX +", " +touchY);
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }```
````

Comment: Why not just store the (x,y) points and 'redraw' them later when necessary? (Or is that what you're asking help for?)

Comment: If I store only the X and Y point, will it draw only a straight line? They are only 2 points and I needs to draw every possible shape the user wants, not only geometrical ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the (x,y) points and 'redraw' them later when necessary.

By (x,y), I mean the `event` `getX` & `getY` values. Store all the values in an `ArrayList`, and then you can use the stored values to redraw your shape. Basically, I'm suggesting you do something along the following lines,

**Create a points array**

```
ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Store touch points in array**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            System.out.println(touchX +", " +touchY);

            points.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(touchX, touchY));
            //At this point you might want to
            //store this array somewhere 
            //so you can use it to redraw later if needed

            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

**You can use the array to redraw the shape when needed**

```
public void drawFromArrayList(ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> points) {
    int pointCount = points.size();
    if (pointCount < 2) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<pointCount;i++) {
        float touchX = points.get(i).first, touchY = points.get(i).second;
        if(i==0) {
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        }
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        if(i==pointCount-1) {
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
        }
    }
}
```